# pip3 vs python3 -m pip vs python3.7 -m pip

Tags: python, pip, package

On my system(Linux Mint), I have `ptyhon2`, `python3.6` and `python3.7`.

```
muyustan@mint:/usr/lib$ pip -V

Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pip

muyustan@mint:/usr/lib$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
muyustan@mint:/usr/lib$ python3 -m pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
muyustan@mint:/usr/lib$ python3.7 -m pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.7)
muyustan@mint:/usr/lib$
```

from these, I understand that `pip` is reserved to `python2` and it's not installed. No problem, since I don't care about `python2`.

It looks like there are two different `pip`s of `python3.6` and `python3.7` respectively.

However when I inspect the folder `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, I see there aren't more than one `pip`.

```
muyustan@mint:/usr/lib$ ll /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages | grep "pip"
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 Mar 21 15:24 pip/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 21 15:24 pip-9.0.1.egg-info/
```

I am pretty confused about `pip3` , `python3 -m pip` and `python3.7 -m pip`.

I assume `python3` refers to `python3.6`.

So my questions are,

1. Do I have 3 different `pip`s ?
2. Which one should I use?
3. What is the actual difference of `pip` between `python3.6` and
   `python3.7`?

Comment: I would install your own version of Python.  the system one often lacks core functions, and if it breaks, your OS breaks.

Comment: _Which one should I use?_ I agree with Simon, and will add that I recommend using virtual environments.

Comment: @Simon what do you mean by "your own version of Python" ?

Comment: @AMC same for you.

Comment: I mean, install python yourself, (yes yet another installation of it), but it's much safer that way

Comment: @Simon I already installed `python3.7` by myself? ( by `sudo apt install python3.7` )

Comment: In which case that's the one to use.   Just stay away from the preinstalled ones

Comment: @Simon so, when I want to install a package, how should I do it? By `python3.7 -m pip install xxxxxxx` ?

Comment: Yes.  That is the one.

Comment: Its okay to use the existing pythons, but avoid using pip with them. If you stick with python modules packaged for your system you may not have the most up-to-date versions of the module, but it will integrate with the existing packages. I didn't follow my own advice and will likely wipe my machine and reinstall on the next major release of my distro.

Comment: @tdelaney "but avoid using pip with them.", so what is your recommendation on how I should install packages?

Comment: On linux mint, suppose you wanted `geopandas`, that would be `sudo apt install python3-geopandas`

Comment: @tdelaney by this way, will I get more up-to-date packages or more-stable packages?

Comment: You will get more-stable packages. Sometimes you can find a PPA (alternate debian repository) that holds more up-to-date stuff. But the distro level stuff is really good if you plan to distribute your code to other people who don't know python. If your module isn't in a distro package or you want the latest stuff, setup a virtual environment and pip install into there.

Comment: In my last job I distributed python modules as .deb., .rpm, .msi and .whl to let everyone pick their poison. Thank goodness for auto build tools.

Comment: @muyustan I always recommend Conda for managing packages and environments.

Comment: @AMC by "conda" do you mean "Anaconda" ?

Comment: @muyustan In this case I'm referring specifically to Conda, I personally don't use the Anaconda distribution. It can get quite confusing, you can find a solid explanation of many topics surrounding Conda [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this topic, the best reference I know of currently is in [*Brett Cannon*'s article "*Why you should use `python -m pip`*"](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/).

In short:

- don't install *pip* (ever)
- instead create virtual environments, they come with *pip* preinstalled, use it to install Python projects within this virtual environment exclusively, also this *pip* can be safely upgraded
- don't use any `pip`, `pip3`, `pip3.7` script directly (ever, unless you are 100% sure it is associated with the right Python interpreter)
- instead use *pip*'s *executable module*

  - `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip somecommand ...`
  - `path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip somecommand ...`
  - (this is also valid for other tools: `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pytest`)
  - (even more so in files such as *bash* scripts, *tox* configurations, documentation, etc.; shortcuts such as `pip` are for interactive command line use only)
  - (using an explicit path additionally makes it possible to use *pip* or such other tools without having to activate the virtual environment)

Comment: After some research, I must say that the issue is too complicated and one should go with this approach rather than insisting to understand whole story behind this confusion.

Comment: @muyustan The complications mostly come from the vast amount of well-intentioned but slightly misleading advice that can be found all around (in my opinion).